# User saving his list before submit in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Hi i want to give two options for the user for his listing as, 1. Save 2. save and publish
How could i do this in ruby on rails

Comment: `published` could be a field in `Listing` model, which can be updated to true on 'Save and Publish'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `f.submit` value is passed as a `commit` message and is available in params. You can give two submit buttons.

```
<%= f.submit 'Save' %>
<%= f.submit 'Save and Publish' %>
```

So in the controller you can do something like this

```
if params[:commit] == 'Save'
  # do something
else
  # do something else
end
```

If you want to have more than 2 use an `elsif` as well.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a field name `status` to the lists table,
if saved and not published ,set it to `saved`,
if published, set it to `published`